# How to install a SM-D-ES3G-48-P in a ISR 4451

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-isr

While plugin a SM-D-ES3G-48-P into a ISR4451 the SM module didn't come up. What steps are needed to setup this SM into the ISR4451.

Google only show me install documents for Catalyst Switches. Anyone can show me the steps for a ISR 4451?

Comment: I don't believe that is compatible with the 4451. The 4K series routers use the SM-X modules.

Comment: Hm this is the same as I searching with google. Then our vendor send the wrong module :-(

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deleted.
SM-D module only work on ISR G2 series..

Comment: The link is for SM-X module instead of SM-D

Comment: Oh. SM-D-ES3G module doesn't have compatibility list on ISR 45XX series.